# Why does ExcludeFromPackageFolders not work for msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, build-process, msdeploy

I've been trying to figure out how to exclude folders from being deployed as part of my web site.  This needs to happen whether it's deployed from within Visual Studio, or whether it's deployed as part of a msbuild task on TFS build server.

Here's my .pubxml file.  It works within Visual Studio (i.e. `bin` and `build` folders are not published), but the ExcludeFromPackageFolders seems to be totally ignored when TFS server builds it.  What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <publishUrl>\\server\site\folder</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="bin">
      <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="build">
      <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFolders>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Team Build servers do not read or use .pubxml files.

If you have a Web Application then you will get a _PublishedWebsites/[websitenane] folder with only what you need for deployment in it automatically. And you need the bin folder contents.

If you have a Web Site you should convert it to a Web Apolication before proceeding as Web Sites are no well supported and will likely be fazed out.

Comment: I already have a TFS build that is using the .pubxml file just fine.  All you have to do is specify the publishing profile as part of the MS Build arguments.  This is already a Web Application, and I actually do not need the bin contents in this case.